# React + Electron + react-hot-loader + react-router + webpack-dev-server

Tags: reactjs, webpack, react-router, electron, webpack-dev-server

## Description

Please, I'm desperate. For the last 3 days, I've been trying without luck to implement react-hot-loader within an electron app and don't know what else to try. I'm following many comments, posts, issues trying to replicate what they did but none gives me enough information about the entire setup so I can find what I'm missing. I've already tried electron-webpack but it didn't work for me. It has HMR from webpack, but no react-hot-loader and that makes applications using react-router a pain to work with. Maybe it's not possible, but people seem to have achieved it so I'm not willing to give up.

## Expected behavior

Project setup with electron, webpack, webpack-dev-server, react, react-router, react-hot-loader. I want to be able to change CSS and HTML strings without having to rebuild the entire project with webpack and restart it.

## Actual behavior

Looking for the right styles in a component accessed through react-router links takes forever. Can't keep doing this. I've been using the dev tools for that purpose but it's not even close to the speed achievable by trying things in an IDE.

## Environment

Deps:

- electron 4.2.10
- webpack-cli 3.3.7
- webpack-dev-server 3.8.0
- webpack 4.39.3
- react-hot-loader 4.12.12
- react-router-dom 5.0.1,

System:

- OS Ubuntu 18.04 LTS
- node 10.16.2
- npm 6.9.0
- yarn 1.7.3

## Reproducible Demo

This is the project I'm trying to set it up for https://github.com/nahuelarjonadev/kafka-lens/, but I'm ultimately looking for just a super simple working demo so I can mirror the configurations or at least get a hint on how to do it. I couldn't find one yet.

Answer (score 0):

Use the webpack react electron boilerplate and add on it the react-hot-reloader or whatever else you want to add, i am sure that will probably work, is a good starting point for sure.

https://github.com/electron-react-boilerplate/electron-react-boilerplate